# Fonte não é reconhecida na geração de PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net, itextsharp

Estou usando a biblioteca ITextSharp para criação de PDF's e estou tendo problemas com a fonte do documento, tenho o erro "Font is an ambiguous", já procurei em diversos lugares e todos os exemplos acabam dando o mesmo erro, alguém sabe como corrigir isso ou tem a documentação da biblioteca para que eu possa utilizar?

Exemplo do código que estou utilizando e obtendo o erro que falei.

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(aluno.Nome, new Font(Font.Bold, 14));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Só falta o nome da fonte, que pode resolver pelo menos esse problema no código:

```
var font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 14, Font.Bold);
var p = new Paragraph(aluno.Nome, font);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/FontPdf.cs).

É possível ver [documentos da biblioteca no Github](https://github.com/itext). Também tem a [documentação das classes](http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs-itextsharp/Index.html).

Comment: Valeeu big, resolveu o problema e agora vou poder dar uma boa olhada nessa biblioteca.